# shell script with hive command not wriritng data to file when call in crontab

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hive, sh

I have a shell script like **`getlist.sh`** it has a below hive command inside it.

```
`hive -e "select * from databasename.tablename where name = 'myname';" > /home/testuser/list.tsv`
```

when run the `getlist.sh` manually it works fine, when I schedule it using cron it creates the file but with no record in it.

Can someone correct me, couldn't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to run the script where the cron executes or is it a different machine?

Comment: I think `hive` is not in `/usr/bin` or `/bin`, so you have to specify `$PATH`.

Comment: @ Maxmithun same machine.

Comment: @Ipor yea I have added the env variables in the shell already

Comment: And `hive` runs fine from shell, but not **from cron**.

Comment: @Ipor yes i guess

Comment: @Ipor i have another schell script which calls in a HQL script to do some Deletion operation in hive it works fine with cron. which put me under assumption that hive with cron is working fine. it has something to do with Unix

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` in `getlist.sh` script. it did the trick.

Comment: There was no `#!/bin/sh` in the script you included in the question.